# Problema para usar el output de una función int y poder imprimirlo en el int main. C++

Tags: c++, funciones

Soy un poco nuevo en la programación y sobre todo en c++. Tengo problemas para poder imprimir el output de una función int, necesito que dicho output se pueda imprimir cuando yo lo llame en mi función main.
Dicha función corresponde a crear un menú para seleccionar dos equipos de futbol y que dichos equipos se puedan seguir llamando dentro de todo el resto del programa. Ya logré que se pueda imprimir el menú, que el usuario escoja a dichos equipos y que se muestren, sin embargo, no logro que se puedan imprimir fuera de la función que cree. Lo siguiente ocurre dentro de la funcion int *solicitarEquipos(char *menuEquipos[])

```
int *solicitarEquipos(char *menuEquipos[]){
    int numEquipo1, numEquipo2;
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
      cout<<"["<< i+1 <<"]"<<"...."<<menuEquipos[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Digite el equipo 1 ";
    cin>> numEquipo1;
    cout<< "El equipo 1 (casa) selecionado es: "<< menuEquipos[numEquipo1-1] <<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Digite el equipo 2 ";
    cin>> numEquipo2;
    cout<< "El equipo 2 (Visita) selecionado es: " << menuEquipos[numEquipo2-1] <<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    do{
    if (numEquipo1==numEquipo2){
     cout<<" !!!!!!El equipo 2 no puede ser el mismo que el equipo 1 por favor seleccione otro equipo!!!!!! "<<endl;
       cout<<"Digite el equipo 2 ";
    cin>> numEquipo2;
    cout<< "El equipo 2 selecionado es: " << menuEquipos[numEquipo2-1] <<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    }
  }while (numEquipo1==numEquipo2);

    int retorno[2]={numEquipo1,numEquipo2};
    return retorno;
}
```

Luego utilizo lo siguiente para poder usarlo e imprimirlo en int main:

```
   char *menuEquipos[12] = {"Equipo1", "Equipo2", "Equipo3","Equipo4","Equipo5","Equipo6","Equipo7","Equipo8","Equipo9","Equipo10","Equipo11","Equipo12"};

  int *testingEquipos= solicitarEquipos(menuEquipos); //Esto se utilizara para llamar a la funcion
    cout<< "UT solicitar equipos:output"<<endl;
    // apartir de aquí comienza el problema. Esto se hizo para probar que testingEquipos[0]y[1] puedan imprimir los nombres de los equipos
    cout<< testingEquipos<<endl; //apartir de aqui no se muestra ningun error solamente se imprime un 0
    cout<<"equipo1: "<< testingEquipos[0]<<endl;// cuando llega aqui el programa no sigue imprimiendo.
    cout<<"equipo2: "<< testingEquipos[1]<<endl;
```

Aclaro que los nombres de los equipos no son relevantes por el momento. Muchas gracias por la ayuda :(

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te sucede es que en la función estás devolviendo un puntero hacia una variable que deja de existir en cuanto sale de la función. La variable `retorno` es local, y solo tiene existencia dentro de la función.

- Puedes optar por guardar retorno en una variable global:

  ```
    int equipos[2];

    void solicitarEquipos(...){
        ...
        equipos = retorno;
    }

    int main(){
        solicitarEquipos(...);
        //Aquí también podrás leer la variable equipos
        ...
    }
  ```
- Puedes retornar un puntero como deseas, pero debes tener los cuidados necesarios, ya que para hacerlo deberás crear el objeto con `new`, en el heap. Luego de usarla debes borrarla con `delete`:

  ```
    int* solicitarEquipos(...){
        ...
        int* retorno = new int[2] { numEquipo1, numEquipo2 };
        return retorno;
    }

    int main(){
        int* equipos = solicitarEquipos(...);
        // Usa equipos y cuando termines liberas la memoria
        delete[] equipos;
        ...
    }
  ```

  Si no quieres preocuparte de la memoria puedes usar los punteros inteligentes `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` y `std::weak_ptr` del header `<memory>`.
- Puedes pasar una variable por referencia y almacenar los valores ahí.

  Hay varias maneras de lograrlo. Estos ejemplos ([tomados de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724184)) tienen el mismo efecto:

  ```
    void foo(int * x);
    void foo(int x[100]); // Los arreglos decaen en punteros 
    void foo(int x[]);
  ```

  Implementando uno en tu código:

  ```
    void solicitarEquipos(..., int guardar[]){
        ...
        guardar[0] = numEquipo1;
        guardar[1] = numEquipo2;
    }

    int main(){
        int almacen[2];
        solicitarEquipos(..., almacen);
        ...
    }
  ```

En cuanto a `cout<< testingEquipos<< endl;`, imprime la dirección de memoria a la que está apuntando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, casi logro resolverlo con int* retorno = new int[2] { numEquipo1, numEquipo2 };
    return retorno;          Sin embargo, a la hora de imprimir, me sale el numero del equipo y no el nombre como tal (equipo1, equipo2 o equipo12....etc.)

Comment: Recuerda que debes liberar la memoria luego de terminar de usarla. `delete` para un elemento, `delete[]` para un arreglo.

Comment: @DrNeo te diste cuenta que estás usando `int` en lugar de `char`?

Comment: En que parte, perdón?

Comment: En toda la función `solicitarEquipos`. Y en `int *testingEquipo`

Comment: En lugar de recomendar que use `new` y `delete`, mejor recomiendale que use
`std::unique_ptr`, menos cosas de las que tiene que preocuparse. O mejor, en este
caso es mucho mejor usar `std::array` o `std::vector`.

Comment: Sí, estoy usando int por que no me permite usar el char.  No se si se pueda usar otra forma para lograr eso. @Pablochaches, gracias por el consejo

Comment: No me he fijado en que es lo que hace, pero si lo que querias era usar es un `char*`, supongo que estas pasando strings, asi que en este caso lo que puedes usar es `std::string`, esa se encargara de todo. Si no son strings lo que estas pasando, hay me avisas, puede que haya otra cosa que te pueda ayudar.